# Need help in accessing and modifying parent form value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

I have 1 label in Form1.

Now i am performing some operation in Form2.(My form1 is already open)

Now i want to update the label of Form1 through some method of Form2.

```
        Form1 frm=new Form1();
        Label label = frm.label1;
        MethodInvoker action = () => label.Text = "Finished";
        label.BeginInvoke(action);
```

This is the code which i have written in form1.
but i am getting following exception:
"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."

So what is the solution?

Comment: In the code example you create a NEW form1, in you question you say you already have an instance of form1. Which one is correct?

Comment: call `label.Handle` before assigning "Finished" to `Label.Text`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in your `Form2?` and you say `Form1` is already open? You are not going to access `Form1` this way because you are creating a new form, instead of using the existing one.

You are getting this error because you have not shown the form yet, and therefor it has no `Handle`. You could force a handle before showing the window by `CreateHandle`, I think, but that won't be a solution for you in this case.

Is `Form2` a modal form? Then you could expose the new label text as a property of `Form2` and retrieve it with `Form1`.

`Form1`:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
Label1.Text = frm.NewLabelText;
```

`Form2`:

```
public string NewLabelText
{
   get { return this.myMethodToGetLabelText(); }
}
```

if the form is not modal and should update your best bet would probably be to use `delegates`